# Run pngquant through an Ant task

Tags: ant, png

I've been attempting unsuccessfully to create a custom Ant task that processes a bunch of PNG files using pngquant.

Here's what I've been trying to so far (and I've been running it as a part of the HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script, so that's where the dynamic values are coming from):

```
<apply executable="${basedir}/${dir.build.tools}/pngquant" dest="./${dir.publish}/${dir.images}/" osfamily="unix">
    <fileset dir="./${dir.source}/${dir.images}/" includes="**/*.png"  excludes="${images.bypass}, ${images.default.bypass}"/>
    <arg value="-force 256"/>
    <targetfile/>
    <srcfile/>
    <mapper type="identity"/>
</apply>
```

Currently, each image errors with "cannot open for reading".

I know this may not be very helpful, but I really don't know where to go from here. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the problem is, but I think there are something wrong with your Ant XML itself.

First of all, your `excludes` has a additional space after the comma.

> excludes: comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be excluded.

*That is to say, you should either use comma, or space, not together. So it should be `${images.bypass},${images.default.bypass}`.* ---- I found that it is not right. It uses `StringTokenizer(String sInput, String sDelimiter, boolean bReturnTokens)` and passes false to the third parameter, so that you can use `,` together.

Also, I recommend you use nested `<include>` and `<exclude>` element to make it more clear.

Second, you don't need to put `<targetfile/>` and `<srcfile/>` inside `<apply>` if you don't need to use them.

Third, `<arg value="-force 256" />` should be `<arg value="-force"/>` and `<arg value="256"/>`.